# C# static variable only when object exists?

Tags: c#, static

I am trying to avoid passing a settings class to every single function.

In C# is it possible to create a static-like variable that goes away once a "host" class disappears?  For example, in the following snippet, I would want the second test case to have an uninitialized value.

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    class Settings
    {
        public int? GetX() { return x_; }
        public void SetX(int x) { x_ = x; }
        private static int? x_ = null;
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        Settings settings = new Settings();
        int? x1 = settings.GetX(); // is null
        settings.SetX(23);
        int? x2 = settings.GetX(); // equals 23
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod2()
    {
        Settings settings = new Settings();
        int? x1 = settings.GetX(); // equals 23 but I want null
    }
}
```

I was able to do this in C++ using shared_ptr and weak_ptr.  Once the Settings instance left the scope, the shared_ptr disappeared and only the weak reference remained, and the memory was freed.

I have considered dependency injection, but I am stuck with the same issue of needing a static reference to a ServiceCollection.

Comment: This is a rather weird requirement, perhaps even a [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). One way I thought of was using `IDisposable`, and declaring the objects using a `using var` statement, and then setting `_x` back to null in `Dispose`.

Comment: I am not beholden to any static behaviour being attached to an existing object.  But I do want more control over the scope of when a "static" variable is no longer "static".  [ThreadStatic] is not useful for me because I am working on an API context.

Comment: Not sure how you want this to work when you have multiple `Settings` objects in scope? Would `GetX()` return a different value for each of them? If not, then which setting's value should it return?

Comment: If you want to limit the scope of static member then it is not a candidate to be static.

Comment: *I am trying to avoid passing a settings class to every single function.* Why not pass it to the constructor of `UnitTest1` and store it as a member variable? Then you won't need to pass it to every method call.

Comment: In a C++ weak_ptr/shared_ptr setup, the instance would disappear once the last shared_ptr exits scope.  So if you have two Settings objects in scope, then it would be the same x_ variable.  Again, I am not beholden to this idea... I am simply trying to find a way not to have to pass a settings object into every downstream function, but not have a static variable for the entirety of the program.

Comment: @JohnWu this is exactly the type of thing I want to avoid.  if UnitTest1 utilizes another class, then Settings needs to be passed there also.

Comment: @Chetan hence, static-like

Comment: In C++ it is possible to execute something in destructor so it runs when the variable goes out of scope. In C# there is no such thing, and it is impossible to reliably and deterministically run anything automatically when a variable goes out of scope. Some similar thing you can do is using disposable and `using` keyword, but if you forgot to dispose just once somewhere, you will ruin your whole program.

Answer (score 0):

See if this solution works for you.

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    class Settings
    {
        private static int? x_ = null;
        private int? localx_ = null;
        public int? X
        {
            get { return x_; }
        }
        public int? LocalX
        {
            get { return localx_; }
            set { 
                localx_ = value;
                x_ = value;
            }
        }
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        Settings settings = new Settings();
        int? x1 = settings.LocalX; // is null
        int? x1_1 = settings.X;// is null
        settings.LocalX = 23;
        int? x2 = settings.LocalX; // equals 23
        int? x2_1 = settings.X; // equals 23
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod2()
    {
        Settings settings = new Settings();
        int? x1 = settings.LocalX; // is null
        int? x2 = settings.X; // equals 23
    }
}
```